# String concatenation in Perl involing the output of functions and the like

Tags: perl, string-concatenation

The following code outputs nothing:

```
print (1 == 2)."a";
```

As does this:

```
print qw< One Two Three > . "a";
```

But this outputs a snowman followed by the letter a, as expected:

```
print chr(0x2603)."a";
```

Is there a general method of concatenating general "things", for lack of a better word (such as function output and the results of boolean comparisons) with string fragments that always works? Because the `.` operator doesn't seem to be reliable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is expected behavior due to the way lists and contexts work in Perl.

**What's Happening**

The line

```
print (1 == 2)."a";
```

Is parsed like this:

```
( print( 1 == 2 ) . "a" )
```

Since `1==2` returns an empty string, nothing is printed. The return value from `print` itself is then concatenated with `a` and discarded.

If you had turned on `use warnings` (which you should always do, along with `use strict`) you would have seen:

> print (...) interpreted as function at -e line 1.
>   Useless use of concatenation (.) or string in void context at -e line 1.

The line

```
print qw< One Two Three > . "a";
```

Does, in fact, print the string `Threea`. That's because `qw< One Two Three >` is equivalent to the expression `( 'One', 'Two', 'Three' )`. The concatenation operator `.` puts that expression in scalar context, and the behavior of the comma operator in scalar context is to return its right-hand operand. The expression thus reduces to `Threea`. Again, if you had `warnings` on, you would have seen:

> Useless use of a constant ("One") in void context at -e line 1.
>   Useless use of a constant ("Two") in void context at -e line 1.

**The moral of the story**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Comment: The warnings are useful, unfortunately (1) these particular warnings would be incredibly cryptic to beginning programmers, and could throw experienced programmers for a loop, and (2) given the information available to the interpreter, I can't imagine getting clearer warnings for these problems.